# Is it possible to embed a StackedInline in another StackedInline with Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, nested, inlines

I think the title is self-explanatory. I this possible with the actual django version ?
Thk in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. (Plus some text to make it up to 30 chars).

Comment: And is there a known workaround for the situation? I guess I'm not the first one facing this issue, but I cannot manage to find a good solution

Comment: There is a patch(http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) out there to allow nested inlines, but it's quite old, and I think there are good reasons for it not been commited to trunk. Has someone ever used this patch, and if so, how stable is it?

Comment: I used to maintain the patch. I haven't tried to test it with 1.3ish versions, but looking at the code, not that much seems to have changed. There were some issues which I never really resolved (and my need for nested inlines went away). I am looking into revisiting the issue though.

Comment: It seems that they are willing to accept the patch now! Have you considered revisiting?